# Javascript property function execution

Tags: javascript, properties

I have an model Object. One of the properties is a function to connect to an api and retrieve some values.  I may have this out of order or need to create some sort of "Helper" function to do this correctly but I wanted to ask this question first.

```
var BuildInfo = {
    arch: function getArch(){
       // connect to api and return values
    }
}
module.exports = BuildInfo;
```

How can I get this populate the arch property or do I need getArch function somewhere else and just return the results as an array to the arch property?

Comment: What do you wish to happen when you do `BuildInfo.arch()`? Or do you want to be able to just use `BuildInfo.arch` as if it was a property and have your function executed only when necessary?

Comment: well the way you have it something would need to call whateverTheReferenceIsCalled.getArch() to make the call....

Comment: I want arch to be populated with the results of getArch().

Answer (score 0):

One strange idea comes to mind, if you really want something that *looks* like a property but is *actually* an asynchronous function call. Within an `async` function, you can `var array = await BuildInfo.arch`, assuming it looks like this:

```
var BuildInfo = {
  get arch() {
    // connect to api and return values
    return someAsynchronousAPIThatReturnsAPromise()
  }
}
module.exports = BuildInfo;
```

#### Demo

```js
var BuildInfo = {
  get arch() {
    return Promise.resolve(['arch', 'info', 'array'])
  }
}

async function getMyArchInfo() {
  var array = await BuildInfo.arch
  
  console.log(array)
}

getMyArchInfo()
```

Comment: This is interesting and may be a viable solution.  let me clarify some things properly also. This application is an express app and I am trying to populate a form. The form will have different value for ul elements to select from that is being populated from an API. It will also have multiple API calls to populate properties which I want to render as ul elements. Part of me thinks I should scratch using a function for the property and have a helper module to do the work and populate the model.  Just trying to learn the best and most efficient way to populate the form. Hope this makes sense

Comment: @fabricatedmind If you have multiple API calls, you can implement them all as get methods similar to above and replace `await BuildInfo.arch` with `await Promise.all([BuildInfo.arch, SomeOtherModule.asyncProperty, ...])` so that they can be fetched in parallel, rather than awaiting each one at a time, which would force them to be fetched in series.